# Excel VBA - Two Variable Vlookup?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to VBA (or any code for that matter) and don't use it much, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do this.

I have two Excel sheets populated with data. I'm trying to take the Part Number and Next Higher Part Number in Columns A and B of Sheet 1 and look for the same Part Number and Next Higher Part Number in Columns A and F of Sheet 2. If a match is found, then I want it to pull over data from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1 (e.g. pull the data in Column B in Sheet 2 to Column M in Sheet 1).

```
Sub EEE_Reformat()

  Dim wb1 As Workbook
  Dim cell1 As Range, rng1 As Range, cell2 As Range, rng2 As Range
  Dim Cel As Range
  Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
  Dim Sht2 As Worksheet

  Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

  Set Sht1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set Sht2 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet2")

  Set Cel = Sht1.Range("A2")
  Set rng1 = Range(Cel, Cel.Offset(Sht1.Cells.Rows.Count - Cel.Row, 0).End(xlUp))
  Set Cel = Sht2.Range("A2")
  Set rng2 = Range(Cel, Cel.Offset(Sht2.Cells.Rows.Count - Cel.Row, 0).End(xlUp))

For i = 2 To 2500
  If Sht1.Cells(i, 13) = "" Then  'if current cell in column 13 is empty then...
    For Each cell2 In rng2        'for each cell in range 2 defined above (column A in Sheet2)...
      For Each cell1 In rng1      'for each cell in range 1 defined above (column A in Sheet1)...
        If cell2.Value = cell1.Value And cell2.Offset(i, 5) = cell1.Offset(i, 1).Value Then   'if the value of cell2 equals the value of cell1 AND the value of cell2 (offset by 5 columns) equals the value of cell1 (offset by 1 columns) then...
          cell1.Offset(i, 12).Value = cell2.Offset(i, 1).Value    'from to Sheet1 column B to Sheet2 column M
          cell1.Offset(i, 13).Value = cell2.Offset(i, 2).Value    'from to Sheet1 column C to Sheet2 column N
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    Next
  End If
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: What section of your code doesn't work? Do you have any sample data you can provide to help test your algorithm?

Comment: Also... you should fully specify your `Range` references. Even though you're using `Cel` inside the `Range`, Excel assumes you're referring to the currently active sheet. Try `Set rng1 = Sht1.Range(Cel, ...` and then `Set rng2 = Sht2.Range(Cel, ...` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Why do you want to do that with code? What you describe can be done with formulas. Post a data sample and the expected result, so we can test our suggestions.

Comment: Add a column in sheet1 that concatenates colums A & B, then add a column in sheet2 that concatenates columns A & F; use `INDEX+MATCH` for the lookup.

Comment: @teylyn it definitely doesn't have to be VBA. Someone told me it could be done using the Index command, but I haven't been able to figure it out. What is the easiest way to post sample data?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon someone else had recommended that as well...trying to figure it out right now

Comment: Once you get the hang of it, you'll never want to use VLOOKUP ever again! It's `=INDEX(result_column, MATCH(lookup_value, where_its_at, 0))`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon awesome thanks a lot this worked well

Comment: Great! Now the relative position of columns is no longer relevant, and your lookups will never break when a column is inserted! Cheers!